# How to load HTML fragment on-demand in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, microservices

There are tons of examples of how to use AngularJS routing to load HTML and scripts dynamically. My scenario is different, and I can't find how to do it.

Assume that this code is already loaded into the browser:

```
<div ng-controller='masterController'>
    <button ng-click='loadOtherHtmlOnDemandAndAppendItAfterMe'></button>
</div>
<script>
    app.controller('masterController', ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.loadOtherHtmlOnDemandAndAppendItAfterMe = function() {
            /* 
              how can I load another HTML file,
              that contains it's related script too here, on-demand
            */
        };
    }]);
</script>
```

Now I understand that a lot of people might now yell that **You're doing it wrong, that's not how AngularJS should work**, and stuff, yet we're stuck at an architecture of micro-services and mashup web UI, where a module loaded into the browser fires an event saying that it needs a functionality, and another module that is listening to that event, should load the related functionality on-demand. URL does not change, and routing is not used here.

Answer (score 2):

just use a [`templateCache`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache) with the [`compile`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) service, this way:

```
app.controller('masterController', ['$scope', '$compile', '$templateCache', function($scope, $compile, $templateCache){
   $scope.loadOtherHtmlOnDemandAndAppendItAfterMe = function() {
      var template = $compile($templateCache.get('yourHTMLFile.html'))($scope);

      angular.element('div').append(template); //append your compiled element wherever you want
   }
}]);
```

In short: templateCache is a service that grabs an HTML file/script easily and wrap in a variable, and $compile let all dynamic behaviours works (angular bindings, javascript etc.)

Comment: what if there is a controller registered inside that template alongside HTML? Because I get `xController is not a function, got undefined` when loading this template: `<div ng-controller='sampleController'>{{ name }}</div><script>app.controller('sampleController', ['$scope', function($scope){ $scope.name = 'Jack'; }]);</script>`